# How do I get the links in this navigation bar to all be on one line instead of four separate lines?

Tags: navigationbar

[image][image]How do I get the links in this navigation bar to all be on one line instead of four separate lines? I have attached my code from my stylesheet and what my navigation bar currently looks like.  Thank you.[My Code[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b2Mk.png)

Comment: The 3 is the navbar and the "enter image...." is the code. I apologize for the mess up.

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you want help you should provide your code here, instead of pictures, this is a helpful read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question